# Facebook api graph all photos giving empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to get all photos from my facebook pefil but all i got is a empty array data or only the perfil photo, i think that with could be my passport facebook error but with the facebook api im geting empty array too,
i try this,

https://graph.facebook.com/`USERID`/photos?access_token=`USERTOKEN`

i dont know what i'm doing wrong, i tried with photo type uploaded and doesn't work too, i just wanna all perfil photos.

reponse:

```
 {
   "data": []
}
```

Comment: Did the use grant your app user_photos permission?

Comment: you mean on the developer facebook web app ?

Comment: if you don´t know what wizkid means, you probably did not authorize the user with the user_photos permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: thanks for the help , i didn't know i need the authorization from facebook to use all user photos.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still receiving an empty array after obtaining the `user_photos` permission, try adding `type=uploaded` (options are uploaded or tagged), e.g.: `/me/photos?fields=images&type=uploaded&access_token=...)` or in the JS SDK:

```
FB.api("/me/photos", { fields: "images", type: "uploaded" }, (resp) => { console.log(resp) });
```

(Note you can always pass "me" instead of a user ID to get info for the current user)